# How to do external maintenance mode in AWS while keeping site up for internal users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, cloudflare

Can someone point me in the right direction on how you can put a site in AWS into maintenance mode for external users (i.e. people out in the world) but leave the site up for internal users (i.e. those on the corporate network)? Below is our cloud topology:

mysite.abc.com -> CloudFlare -> AWS Route53 -> AWS ELB -> AWS EC2

I can easily put the site into maintenance mode for everyone by simply using weighted routing in Route53 and sending all requests to a maintenance page in CloudFront/S3. I can't figure out how to optionally redirect based on client IP though. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using both CloudFlare and Route 53? They have a lot of overlap in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

ELB and Route53 cannot change traffic based on source IP.

Some options I might employ:

1. create a second domain name, specifically and only known to the internal users
2. make a change in your local (corporate) DNS resolver to point you to the right ELB, while redirecting everyone else (outside).
3. set up a redirecting service on the EC2 instance, for instance by using Nginx, that redirects all non-corporate IPs to the CloudFront and proxy_passes the rest through to your app

The last one is the most flexible and might benefit you in other ways, like being able to do emergency failovers etc

Comment: 4. Code the functionality you require into your website. This is likely to be more effective than the workarounds.